# Save as an Excel file embedded in another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ole, save-as

I want to manage with VBA an Excel file embedded in another Excel file. I can find many results with .docx documents, but I stuck with a .xlsx one.

My last try is using OLE objects, but stuck at the line "SaveAs" (Error 1004).
Here is the weird part: when I start debugging, or if I run the program step by step using F8, it did run, but no file were saved...

I called my OLEObject "TEST" for this example:

```
Sub testOLE()
mPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

For Each obj In Worksheets(1).OLEObjects
 If obj.Name = "TEST" Then
 obj.Verb
 obj.Object.Activate
 obj.Object.SaveAs mPath & "TEST_success.xlsx"
 obj.Object.Close
End If
 i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

I don't understand how to save OLEObjects as .xlsx, could you help me a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had **success** using `obj.Object.SaveCopyAs` instead of `obj.Object.SaveAs`.