# Shell.Application paste method does not create a file in the target folder

Tags: vba

I've seen a few incarnations of the code I've copied below (from this site actually) and just cannot understand why, after the "Paste" instruction, no file is created in the "Temp" folder. No error is thrown.

```
For Each Sh In Sheet1.OLEObjects
  If InStr(1, Sh.Name, "Object", 1) Then
   Sh.Copy
   ' this code paste Embedded Object to folder
   CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Temp\").Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
  End If
 Next Sh
```

The code is running in Excel and is to save embedded PDF files to disk.

Comment: Can't you use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913191/save-as-an-excel-file-embedded-in-another-excel-file)? Copy-paste is gooey anyway.

Comment: @vacip Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work as when you have activated the PDF, there is no way to control the object - e.g. the obj.Object.SaveCopyAs is not a method for this type of object.

That is why I am trying to find any way to take the PDF file and save it to disk. I know it will have additional wrapper text in there as part of the embedding process by Excel, but I know how to strip this out via a hex editor. But, I just can't get the file out to disk in the first place.