# Reading Xlsx from another Xlsx file

Tags: perl

I have few Xlsx files say X.xlsx,Y.xlsx,Z.XLSX and I kept those three Xlsx files in another xlsx file say A.xlsx. Now I want to ready the content in the three xlsx files(x,y,z) at a time through A.xlsx.

Can any one help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is easy on Windows if your target machine also has Microsoft Excel installed.

Use the [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE) module to create an instance of Excel, open your master file `A.xlsx` and then iterate over its `->{OLEObjects}` property:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE 'in';
$ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application') or die "oops\n";
my $Axlsx = $ex->Open('C:\\Path\\To\\A.xlsx');
my $i=0;
for my $embedded (in $Axlsx->OLEObjects) {
    $embedded->Object->Activate();
    $embedded->Object->SaveAs("test$i++.xlsx");
    $embedded->Object->Close;
}
```

After saving them, you can treat them as normal Excel files. Alternatively, you can work directly with `$embedded->Object`, but as you haven't told us what exactly you need to do, it's hard to give specific advice.

See also [Save as an Excel file embedded in another Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913191/save-as-an-excel-file-embedded-in-another-excel-file)